# EasyPHP modules folder conflicts with Drupal

Tags: apache, drupal, httpd.conf, easyphp, mod-alias

I installed EasyPHP and set up a Drupal installation and a virtual host, so that I could see my site at sitename.local in my browser.

At first, it seemed like it was working, but it looked odd. The size of the text was different and certain page elements were displayed that were supposed to be hidden.

I found that the CSS was not loading from /modules/system. This was odd, because other CSS files would load fine. When I tried to access those CSS files directly, EasyPHP would throw "Object not found!"

So I tried navigating in my browser to sitename.local/modules. I would expect it to say "Access forbidden", but instead it showed the index of the EasyPHP modules folder.

I looked in httpd.conf and found this line, which seems to be the culprit:

`Alias /modules "${path}/modules"`

If I comment out that line, my site works normally, but I run into errors in EasyPHP because the module path is not found.

**Is there way to rewrite this line so that it only redirects 127.0.0.1/modules and not sitename.local/modules?**

Answer (score 3):

Jus run into the same problem on EasyPHP 14.1VC11 and Drupal 7.26
Adding alias in virtualhost configuration worked for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     DocumentRoot path-to-site-folder
     ServerName site-name

     Alias /modules "path-to-site-folder/modules"

     <Directory "path-to-site-folder">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Deny from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is actually the answer posted by @ahokkonen, but without the `**`.

So, adding `Alias /modules "path-to-site-folder/modules"` solves the issue (I just did this and it works.